# What are some of the best beaches without large crowds in Japan that are good to visit in September/October?

Tags: japan, beaches

What are some of the best beaches in Japan that meet the following criteria:

1) no large crowds,

2) good to visit in September/October (no heavy rainfalls, good weather)?

Comment: Hi rehband and welcome to Travel.SE. Your question is very subjective and vague and it's like to be put on hold soon. You can visit our [help center](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help) for more information.

Comment: Easy to answer- Kamogawa- its just only slightly popular. The beaches are far from packed. Lots of services are lightly used. Accomodation is cheap except for Obon- around 15th August.

Answer (score 1):

Subjective information follows: (I live in Tokyo)

1)
Many beaches on the main islands close promptly on August 31, thus removing the crowds. It also removes the services so you will need to pack in everything you need. One of the reasons they close is the cooler water brings in a lot of jellyfish.

If you want services you will have to head south / west toward Okinawa. Expect more crowds as a result, but not as many as Kamakura beach on fireworks day.

2)
September / October is typhoon season, each storm affects about half the country. You get 3-5 days advance notice, enough to change the day trip but not enough to change the air trip.